# Is there a way to add multi steps to a git alias?

Tags: windows, bash, powershell, git-bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm going to create an alias that does this:

I've added it to my git-bash .bash_profile but I'd like to see if there is a way to add it as an alias so I don't have to use git bash

## Git finish will push to current branch                                                                                # Eg. gf "commit message"

```
gf() {                                                                                                                           
 CURRENT_BRANCH="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"                                                                      
 git add . && git commit -m "$1" && git push origin "$CURRENT_BRANCH"                                            
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               # Git merge                                                                                                             # Eg. gm branch-name                                                                                                    
gm() {                                                                                                                           
  git merge "$1"                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               # Git checkout                                                                                                          # Eg. gc branch-name                                                                                                    
gc(){                                                                                                                            
 git checkout "$1" && gp                                                                                         
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a "Git-Subcommand" the name of this executable must be in this Format: `git-{{ Name }}` eg: `git-acommit`. This File must be located in one the Directories listed in `$PATH`, you can now execute `git acommit` and *git* will search for it in you `$PATH`.

To use this than in an alias simply run `git config --global alias.gf acommit` and you are finished. **Please note:** the *alias* step is unnecessary since you can name your file how you want, so you could also name it `git-gf` instead of `git-acommit`.

But without creating a *separated* file it's impossible to stack commands in a git alias.

Or you could use [GitAlias](https://github.com/GitAlias/gitalias) to create an alias that executes a function or multiple Commands.
For an example check out the [Recovery examples](https://github.com/GitAlias/gitalias#recovery-examples) Section.